# ui-router with dynamic views

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I have a simple table that displays data. It has columns at the top which are just the keys from the JSON data.

The data that I receive is dynamic; I don't know what the columns will be named. However, when you click on a column it sorts it in ascending order, or descending depending how many times you click.

I would like to save this state using ui-router, however, I don't know the name of the column ahead of time, so how would I name the view or state? Is there a simple way to do this that is going over my head?

Here is how the table is generated:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="column in columns>
        <a ng-click="$parent.predicate = '\'' + column + '\''; $parent.reverse=!reverse;">{{column}}</a>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="type in data | orderBy:predicate:reverse>
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns"><input ng-model="type[column]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, one can use the for...in loop to iterate over properties. One can access said properties values within the loop. One could in turn use those to populate your model as needed.

For example (taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)):

```
var o = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

function show_props(obj, objName) {
    var result = "";

    for (var prop in obj) {
        result += objName + "." + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(show_props(o, "o")); /* alerts (in different lines): o.a = 1 o.b = 2 o.c = 3 */
```

Using this approach, it shouldn't matter what the column names are or what they contain. Does this help?